# Finding eigenvalues For $A$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can you help me to find a way to get a quick answer for the following problem:

> if $A$ is Real and non-uniform square square matrix and $A^t=A^2$(transposed). Find
>   the eigenvalues For $ A$?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint 1: How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $A^2$ related?

Hint 2: How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $A^t$ related?

Comment: What is a "non-uniform square square matrix"?

Comment: If $A^t = A^2$, then $A = (A^t)^t = (A^2)^t = (A^t)^2 = (A^2)^2 = A^4$.

Comment: There's another recent question around here somewhere that asks about the general case $A^k = A^T$.

Answer (score 0):

From above, $A^{t} = A^{2} \implies A = (A^{t})^{t}  = (A^{2})^{t} = (A^{t})^{2} = (A^{2})^{2} = A^{4}$

If $A= Q \Lambda Q^{t} $ then $A^{4} = (Q\Lambda Q^{t})^{4} = Q \Lambda^{4} Q^{t}$
and $\Lambda^{4}  \implies \lambda_{i}^{4} ,1 \leq i \leq n $

Answer (score 0):

Set $v$ to be an eigenvalue of length one, with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Now try this: multiply by $v^t$ on the left and $v$ on the right. Then $$ v^t A^t v = v^t A^2 v $$

This can be simplified using matrix multiplication associativity, and that $ (AB)^t = B^t A^t $. Can you get an equation that's purely in $\lambda$? Feel free to ask if you don't understand something :)